# C++ : curly brackets with std library type

Tags: c++, std

I try to understand the docs for `std::less`, where the following example is given for the usage with a template.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
 
template <typename A, typename B, typename C = std::less<>>
bool fun(A a, B b, C cmp = C{})
{
    return cmp(a, b);
}
 
int main()
{
    std::cout
      << std::boolalpha
      << fun(1, 2)   << ' ' // true
      << fun(1.0, 1) << ' ' // false
      << fun(1, 2.0) << ' ' // true
      << std::less<int>{}(5, 5.6)    << ' ' // false: 5 < 5 (warn: implicit conversion)
      << std::less<double>{}(5, 5.6) << ' ' // true: 5.0 < 5.6
      << std::less<int>{}(5.6, 5.7)  << ' ' // false: 5 < 5 (warn: implicit conversion)
      << std::less{}(5, 5.6)         << ' ' // true: less<void>: 5.0 < 5.6
      << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
true false true false true false true
```

My question is:

How is a `std::` function used as a template argument?

And in this concrete case, why are there curly brackets `{}` behind the `C cmp = C` or in the call `std::less<double>{}(5, 5.6)`?

Comment: `std::less` isn't a function, it's a [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses)

Comment: Classic way to write before uniform unitialisation: `std::less<int>()(5, 5.6)` – a combination of calling the constructor (first pair of parentheses) and then, as `std::less` is callable (has an `operator()`) calling this newly constructed object (second pair of parentheses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demo-code suffers from so-called *'uniform initialisation'* (broken by design, be careful with its use especially in template code!), classic way to write the same code *before* uniform initialisation is:

```
std::less<int>()(5, 5.6); // others analogously
```

`std::less` is a *callable* class, a so-called *'functor'*, which means it provides an `operator()` by which objects of the class can be called just like a function (to be precise: the operator is a member function that gets called, just the syntax for getting called actually is the same).

The code presented now first constructs such an object (calls the constructor; first pair of parentheses) while afterwards the so constructed object is called (the `operator()` with two arguments, second pair of parentheses).

Equivalent code could be:

```
std::less<int> li; // note that the parentheses need to be left out as you would
                   // declare a function then instead of creating an object;
                   // braces for uniform initialisation could remain
li(5, 5.6);
```

Note, though, that the life-time of the object `li` is now longer is longer (until leaving the current *scope*) than the one of the temporary (only current *expression*). In given case, there are no visible side effects, though, notably as `std::less` doesn't have any in its destructor.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! So `std::less<>{ }`is the same as `std::less<>( )`? Ist there some default behaviour functors have when initialised uniformly?

Comment: @lpnorm depending on where they appear, mostly yes, but sometimes the one with `()` is a function declaration.

Comment: @lpnorm There's no difference in *most* cases in between classic and uniform initialisation – issues can arise, though, on selecting the appropriate overload of multiple constructors. `{}` syntax prefers, if there is a suitable one, a `std::initializer_list` constructor over others, e.g. for `std::vector`: `std::vector{1, 7}` creates a vector with two elements `1` and `7`, while `std::vector(1, 7)` creates a vector with seven ones (another overload!).

Comment: Now imagine the initialiser list overload would not have been there initially, then uniform would have called exactly the same constructor as classic; then adding this constructor later would break any code using uniform initialisation already before. You only are safe with classic initialisation: As shown already for seven elements or via `std::vector<int> v({1, 7});` to exactly construct two elements via initialiser list. This gets especially relevant within templates where some types might come with the initialiser list constructor and others not!

Comment: Note, too, that the case @Caleth points out is exactly why the parentheses need to be left out in the equivalent form in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

> How is a `std::` function used as a template argument?

It isn't a function. `std::less` is a class template with one type parameter (which has the default `void`). It has an `operator()` member function, which means instances can be used like functions.

> why are there curly brackets `{}`?

To get a default-constructed instance of the class.

`std::less<T>` has a primary template that compares two `T`s via `<`, but since C++14 `std::less<void>` is an explicit specialisation.
It's `operator()` is itself a member template with two type parameters, approximately:

```
template<>
struct less<void>
{
    template<typename T, typename U>
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const U& rhs)
    { return lhs < rhs;}
};
```

That is, it can compare things of different types, as long as there is an unambiguous `<` between them (which may involve implicit conversions).

Answer (score 1):

`std::less` is actually not a function, it is a struct, the interface of which may be represented in simplified form as follows.

```
template<class T>
struct less
{
    bool operator()(const T& t1, const T& t2)
    { return t1 < t2;}
};
```

In template parameter, as we see, C is actually a **type**(because `std::less<>` is a type). So everything makes sense.

Comment: What happens when you use `std::less<>` without specifying `T`?

Comment: It is instantiated by using the default argument for T, which is `void`. (You can see it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less).